# Codeigniter issue - The configuration file sites/mydomain.com.php does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have a codeigniter app that doesn't seem to 'see' the config file within my 'application' folder and whenever I attempt to load the site locally I get the following error:

```
The configuration file sites/mydomain.com.php does not exist.
```

NB - mydomain.com obviously has been substituted for obvious reasons above :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Configuration file generally is named config.php, had you renamed it? are you sure the file with that name exists.

Comment: are you sure about `.php` ? I have never seen a codeigniter URI with .php extension

Comment: Yes, many ideas! Ideas that can change the world! anyways... coming to your question... have you checked if you haven't changed the "application"  folder name? just to confirm, open your index.php and check for $application_folder = 'application'; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the ideas :-)

I worked it out the previous developer had created an extra directory called 'sites' where there was extra config files that are loaded.

Thanks!